# Popup on left click

Tags: java, swing, menu, awt, jpopupmenu

I am trying to create a popup on a button through the action listener with Java.

I have some code, but I can't get it to work, though I think I'm close!
This code is from an example but for Pmenu.show, I had to remove the first arg, and I don't know what to replace it with, which seems to be the problem here.

```
btnOptions.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                final JPopupMenu Pmenu = new JPopupMenu();
                  JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Cut");
                  Pmenu.add(menuItem);
                  menuItem = new JMenuItem("Copy");
                  Pmenu.add(menuItem);
                  menuItem = new JMenuItem("Paste");
                  Pmenu.add(menuItem);
                  menuItem = new JMenuItem("Delete");
                  Pmenu.add(menuItem);
                  menuItem = new JMenuItem("Undo");
                  Pmenu.add(menuItem);
                  Point location = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
                  Pmenu.show(null, location.getX(), location.getY());
            }
        });
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Component source = (Component)evt.getSource();
Point location = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(location, source
Pmenu.show(source, location.getX(), location.getY());
```

The question that jumps out at me is "why?"  Why do it this way?  What is it your are trying to achieve?

**UPDATE - Popup offset**

This would display the popup centered horizontally against the source control (the button) and under it.

```
Component source = (Component)evt.getSource();
Point location = source.getLocation();
Dimension size = source.getSize();

int xPos = location.x + ((size.width - PMenu.getWidth()) / 2;
int yPos = location.y + size.height;
Pmenu.show(source, xPos, yPos);
```

This is, of course, just an example, you would be able to supply your layout information as you please

**WORKING UPDATE**

```
    Component source = (Component)evt.getSource(); 
    Dimension size = source.getSize(); 

    int xPos = ((size.width - Pmenu.getPreferredSize().width) / 2); 
    int yPos = size.height;

    Pmenu.show(source, xPos, yPos);
```

Because the popup location is relative to the source, we don't need the source's location information

Comment: I have a settings button and when a user clicks it, I want a popup menu to appear. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yeah, that's fine, just curious

Comment: @MichaelScott The main reason I wanted to know, is if you only want to show the popup because of the click, you probably don't need the mouse location.  You can use the position of the button (either absolutely on the screen, or relative as we've already pointed out) and display the popup, for example, under the button

Comment: Ohhh, I am going to look at all this tonight. What would that code look like?

Comment: evt is giving me an error so I had to create a variable just an fyi
EventObject evt = null;

Then I run the program and click the settings button but I get errors
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ComicDownloader$6.actionPerformed(ComicDownloader.java:712)

Line 712 is this
Component source = (Component)evt.getSource();

Comment: @MichaelScott Sorry, I called it `evt` it's actually `e` in your code

Comment: This is my code. The popup, pops up but it's WAYY below the program.

Component source = (Component)e.getSource();
       Point location = source.getLocation();
       Dimension size = source.getSize();

       int xPos = location.x + ((size.width - Pmenu.getWidth()) / 2);
       int yPos = location.y + size.height;
       
       Pmenu.show(source, xPos, yPos);

Comment: @MichaelScott Opps, thought that may happen, my bad, sorry, untested code.  Check out the second update - I've test this one

Comment: Hey Mad, I was too busy over the summer, but I'm back and your new code is PERFECT! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

try passing in the instance of your window. (this).

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html#show%28java.awt.Component,%20int,%20int%29), the first parameter is the

```
invoker - the component in whose space the popup menu is to appear
```

So you want to show the popup menu in the window.

Comment: just as a little clarification, the coordinates past to the invoke method are relative to the supplied component.  If you supply no component reference, then the coordinates are absolute to the screen

Comment: I literally typed in "this"  (no quotes) but that didn't work.

Comment: @Mad Programmer - I looked at that example and their code saus JDigit.this    So I tried btnOptions.this but it tells me to create that class. So I tried another class, which is one of my more "main" class if you will. It was ComicDownloader.this and then .show wants me to remove the arguments.

Comment: `JPopupMenu.show(Component invoker, int x, int y)`.  You need to pass all three parameters.  In your case I'd do something like `JPopupMneu.show((Component)e.getSource(), location.getX(), location.getY());`